# Datepicker date is not being set through jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello all I am trying to set date of datepicker control in jQuery. When I run the page through Mozilla Firefox browser it works fine. However, when I run it in Google Chrome the date is not being set. Does anybody know what the problem is?

```
cookie_value = unescape(a_temp_cookie[1].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''));
var myDate = new Date(cookie_value);
var date1 = new Date(Date.parse(myDate));
date1.setDate(date1.getDate());
var newDate = date1.toDateString();
newDate = new Date(Date.parse(newDate));
var option = "minDate";

$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtArrivalDate").datepicker("option", option, newDate);
// $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtArrivalDate").datepicker("option", option, newDate);
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDepartureDate").datepicker('setDate', newDate);
```

Comment: What is the value of a_temp_cookie[1] ?

Answer (score 0):

Much of your code seems redundant. Why do date1=new Date(....) and then date1.setDate(...)? Why create newDate if it is just a copy of date1?

See: 
http://jsfiddle.net/QB6K6/

It works in chrome for me using the code below.  Depends on the value of your cookie, though.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var cookie_value = unescape(a_temp_cookie[1].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''));
var myDate = new Date(cookie_value);

$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtArrivalDate").datepicker( {minDate:myDate});

$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDepartureDate").datepicker();
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDepartureDate").datepicker("setDate", myDate);

});
```